# Cannot display an image in a function tkinter

Tags: python, image, function, tkinter, tkinter-button

Here is my code

```
def new_grille():
  global cc
  global tab
  global tableau

  x = cc[0]
  y = cc[1]


  fenetre = tk.Tk()
  fenetre.title('Gomoku : Coup joueur Blanc')
  fenetre.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
  fenetre.bind('<Escape>', lambda e: fenetre.destroy())
  fenetre.config(bg='#FFFFFF')


  tableau = tk.Canvas(fenetre, width = 1700, height = 1500, bg ="#FFFFFF")
  tableau.pack(side = tk.BOTTOM, pady=100)

  img = Image.open('boutton quitter.png')
  img_quitter = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)


  boutton_quitter = tk.Button(fenetre, width=45, height=7,image = img_quitter, command=lambda x="": on_closing())
  boutton_quitter.image = img_quitter
  boutton_quitter.place(x=1500, y=100)
  boutton_quitter.pack()
```

Im trying to display on the 'boutton_quitter' button an image ('boutton_quitter.png) but it raise an  error (_tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage13" doesn't exist), ive tried lot of things but nothing worked, pls help me :)

I saw different things, toplevel methods and trying to stock the image in a global function but either i messed up, either it dosnt work

Comment: Is the image in the same folder as the code file?

Comment: Yeah, the image shows up when i use this code out of the function

Comment: Have you created more than one instance of `Tk`? This is the sort of error you get if you've done that.

Comment: You mean smthing like 'fenetre = tk.Tk()' ? If yes, this function is called when a button is clicked on a first window. So yeah, its not the first instance if i understood the question

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: An image can only be used in one root window and it’s children. If you have multiple root windows (which you shouldn’t do), you need to specify which window an image belongs to. There are a few questions on this site already that address this.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use both layout manager `boutton_quitter.place(x=1500, y=100)` `boutton_quitter.pack()`. Use one layout manger to suit your need.

When using `fenetre.attributes('-fullscreen', True)` Don't set. Layout manager value too high such as `place()`. The `pack()` is OK to suit your need.

I comment out that we doesn't need.

Snippet:

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

#cc = 0

def new_grille():
  #global cc
  #global tab
  global tableau


  fenetre = tk.Tk()
  fenetre.title('Gomoku : Coup joueur Blanc')
 # fenetre.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
  fenetre.bind('<Escape>', lambda e: fenetre.destroy())
  fenetre.config(bg='#FFFFFF')


  tableau = tk.Canvas(fenetre, width = 700, height = 500, bg ="#FFFFFF")
  tableau.pack(side = tk.BOTTOM, pady=100)

  img = Image.open('p2.png')
  img_quitter = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)

  boutton_quitter = tk.Button(fenetre, width=250, height=350,image = img_quitter, command=lambda x="": on_closing())
  boutton_quitter.image = img_quitter
  boutton_quitter.place(x=100, y=100)
  #boutton_quitter.pack()
  fenetre.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    new_grille()
```

Screenshot:

[image]